# Use dt.weekofyear for more than a year? (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot some data, simplified over the weekly means. I have data over multiple years.

```
plt.plot(dataframe.groupby(dataframe["DateTime"].dt.weekofyear)["value"].mean())
```

This attempt will give me only the first year as an output. How can I plot the whole timespan?

Comment: If you're grouping by week number, that means week 1 of year x will be grouped with week 1 of year y. Also, according to the docs, [dt.weekofyear is deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekofyear.html#pandas.Series.dt.weekofyear).

Answer (score 0):

The pandas documentation says to use `.isocalendar` now since `.weekofyear()` is deprecated.

So... try using:

```
dt.isocalendar()[1]
```

Here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.isocalendar.html#pandas.Timestamp.isocalendar), dt.isocalendar() returns a tuple, that is why you include the `[1]` by the way. That is how I have seen the week accessed.